# how to update contents of a span tag?

Tags: javascript, html, updates, session-storage

I am creating a web page where the user and select an item by clicking on the button. The details of the item selected will be displayed in a dropbox. At the moment I can get it to update the quantity if the user selects it again. The problem which I am having is, say if the user first click on btnBuy1 (details displayed in dropbox), then clicks on btnBuy2 (again, details are displayed), but when they click on btnBuy2 again , the details from btnBuy2 is updated but the details from btnBuy1 disappears.

```
        $("#btnBuy0").click(function()
        {
            if (!sessionStorage['quantity0'])
            {
                sessionStorage['quantity0'] = 1;
                $("#dropbox").append('<span id = "0"><img class = "thumb" src="../images/21_metoyou.jpg" />' + teddy[0].desc + ", Price £"
             + teddy[0].price + ", Quantity: " + sessionStorage.getItem('quantity0') + "</span><br/>");

            }           
            else
            {
                sessionStorage['quantity0']++;
                $("#dropbox").html('<span id = "0"><img class = "thumb" src="../images/21_metoyou.jpg" />' + teddy[0].desc + ", Price £"
             + teddy[0].price + ", Quantity: " + sessionStorage.getItem('quantity0') + "</span><br/>");

            }
            if (Modernizr.sessionstorage) 
            {  // check if the browser supports sessionStorage
                myids.push(teddy[0].partnum); // add the current username to the myids array
                sessionStorage["ids"]=JSON.stringify(myids); // convert it to a string and put into sessionStorage
            }   
            else 
            {
             // use cookies instead of sessionStorage
            }
        });
        $("#btnBuy1").click(function()
        {
            if (!sessionStorage['quantity1'])
            {
                sessionStorage['quantity1']=1;
                $("#dropbox").append('<span id = "1"><img class = "thumb" src="../images/birthday_metoyou.jpg" />' + teddy[1].desc + ", Price £"
             + teddy[1].price + ", Quantity: " + sessionStorage.getItem('quantity1') + "</span><br/>");

            }
            else
            {
                sessionStorage['quantity1']++;
                $("#dropbox").html('<span id = "1"><img class = "thumb" src="../images/birthday_metoyou.jpg" />' + teddy[1].desc + ", Price £"
             + teddy[1].price + ", Quantity: " + sessionStorage.getItem('quantity1') + "</span><br/>");

            }
            if (Modernizr.sessionstorage) 
            {  // check if the browser supports sessionStorage
                myids.push(teddy[1].partnum); // add the current username to the myids array
                sessionStorage["ids"]=JSON.stringify(myids); // convert it to a string and put into sessionStorage
            } 
            else 
            {
             // use cookies instead of sessionStorage
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a jQuery person but I think your problem is caused by the fact that you're incrementing the count and then replacing all the HTML in the dropbox - vis

```
sessionStorage['quantity0']++;
  $("#dropbox").html('<span id = "0"><img class = "thumb" src="..jpg" />' + 
// there -------^^^^-----  
                       teddy[0].desc + ", Price £"
                     + teddy[0].price + ", Quantity: " + 
                       sessionStorage.getItem('quantity0') + "</span><br/>");
```

shouldn't you be replacing the contents of $("#0") not $("#dropbox") ?? ... i.e.

```
sessionStorage['quantity0']++;
  $("#0").html('<img class = "thumb" src="..jpg" />' + teddy[0].desc + 
                     ", Price £" + teddy[0].price + ", Quantity: " + 
                     sessionStorage.getItem('quantity0'));
```